# How to show custom post category in theme option?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show custom post category in theme option. I have used option tree plugin for this. I have written the following code for that.

```
    array(
    'id'          => 'slider-category',
    'label'       => __( 'Category Checkbox', 'theme-text-domain' ),
    'desc'        => __( 'The Category Checkbox option type displays a list of category IDs.' ),
    'std'         => '',
    'type'        => 'category-checkbox',
    'section'     => 'social-icon',
    'rows'        => '',
    'post_type'   => 'slider',
    'taxonomy'    => 'Categori',
    'min_max_step'=> '',
    'class'       => '',
    'condition'   => '',

  )
```

But it is showing the category from default post section. Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: And what is _option tree plugin_?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

Comment: Whats your custom post type and taxonomy is?